# Why does | work just like the || OR operator?

Tags: javascript

I noticed in my javascript code that I had | instead of the || OR operator, and yet the condition still worked..

```
if( 100>100 | 200>100 ) console.log(true);
```

Is this normal? Why does | work the same as ||?

Comment: `|` is a bitwise operation `0|1` is `1` or true

Comment: Because true/false are automatically converted to 1/0 when you use bitwise operators. And binary AND/OR are isomorphic with logical AND/OR.

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt: *"Why does | work just like the || OR operator?"* **It doesn't.** It's just that the differences in how they work weren't important in your example above. (*One* of the differences is that `|` doesn't short-circuit, but `||` does, which can be very important in some places `||` is used.)

Comment: Thanks- I didn't know it was a bitwise operation. I understand now why it worked in this case.